# How to find references to a particular index?

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing

How do I find all DB references (such az INDEX optimizer hints) to a particular index?

(I plan to drop an index, and need to know whether it has any dependant objects associated.)

Comment: Check for the `DBA_DEPENDENCIES`

Comment: I wonder how an **INDEX** can have any dependencies. Hints are just comments, they are not listed in any dependency table. Maybe have a look at [Index Monitoring](https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/index-monitoring)

Comment: @Narayan SELECT * FROM ALL_DEPENDENCIES WHERE REFERENCED_TYPE = 'INDEX'; only shows a couple of XDB owned results used by some SYS owned objects. No trace of any real index dependencies. (I'm testing this on a large legacy database including hundreds of actual indexes.)

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit You should post this comment as an answer, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Index does not have any dependencies. An Index is based on table(s) and column(s). If you like to know whether an index was used by any query you can use [Index Monitoring](https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/index-monitoring) feature.

You can enable/disable monitoring by

```
ALTER INDEX my_index_i MONITORING USAGE;
ALTER INDEX my_index_i NOMONITORING USAGE;
```

Then you can check index usage in view `v$object_usage`(for release 12.1 and less) or `dba_object_usage`

Answer (score 2):

Especially, This `sql_text` column of this `sql` may be helpful for an individual index :

```
select p.sql_id, q.sql_text, p.access_predicates
  from gv$sql_plan p
 inner join gv$sql q on ( p.sql_id = q.sql_id )  
 where p.object_name = upper('&i_index_name') 
 group by p.access_predicates, q.sql_text, p.sql_id
 order by p.access_predicates, q.sql_text, p.sql_id;
```